# Prove that if p is a prime, a and b are integers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

(a) if p | ab, then either p | a or p | b or both.

(b) if a | b, p | b, but a is not divisable by p , then p | b/a.

I have no problem with the part a I solved that but need some serious help on part b. Like I said I need to learn what means that reversed cross.

Comment: Did you mean $p \nmid a$?

Comment: I think what you call reversed cross was $p\not | a$ which means $p$ does not divide $a$.

Comment: $p = a = 2, b= 6.$ then it is not true. that "reversed cross" means "$p$ does not divide $a$". I think it was written as $p \not| a.$

Comment: I've seen $(a)$ as definition of prime, what is the definition of prime you're working with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$p|b \Rightarrow b = pk,$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}. a|b \Rightarrow b = al,$ for some $l \in \mathbb{Z}.$ Thus $pk = al \Rightarrow p|l,$ since $p\not| a \Rightarrow p |(b/a).$